# Returning original of an object in C++

Tags: c++

I've made my own implementation of the linked list in C++.

```
template <typename Info>
class LinkedList
{
private:
template <typename nInfo>
struct Node
{
    int key;
    nInfo info;
    Node <nInfo>* next;
};

Node <Info>* head;
public:
LinkedList();
bool Push(int _key, Info _info);
void PrintList();
Node<Info>* FindByKey(int _key);
};
```

Then created my own classes Book and ListOfBooks:

```
class Book
{
const char* title;
const char* authorsName;
const char* authorsSurname;
Date borrowDate;
Date dueDate;
bool taken;
public:
Book();
Book(const char* _title, const char* _name, const char* _surname);
friend ostream& operator<<(ostream& os, const Book& _book);
void setTaken(bool flag);
void setBorrowDate(Date _day);
void setDueDate(Date _day);
};


class ListOfBooks
{
LinkedList<Book> books;
public:

void PushBook(const char * _title, const char * _name, const char * _surname);
void BorrowBook(int _key, Date _day);
void PrintBooks();
};
```

And when I want to change the properties of the book I've found by its ID, it seems like it changes just a copy, not the original object.

```
void ListOfBooks::BorrowBook(int _key, Date _day)
{
Book temp = books.FindByKey(_key)->info;
temp.setTaken(true);
temp.setBorrowDate(_day);
temp.setDueDate(_day + 30);
cout << temp << endl; //debuging purposes So i see the copy changes
}
```

Find by key method

```
template<typename Info>
inline LinkedList<Info>::Node<Info>* LinkedList<Info>::FindByKey(int _key)
{
if (head)
{
    Node<Info>* temp = head;
    while (temp->key != _key && temp->next)
        temp = temp->next;
    if (temp->key == _key)
    {
        return temp;
    }
    else
        return nullptr;
}
else
    return nullptr;
}
```

Is there any way to work on the original? If you feel like i've explained the case vaguely, don't hesitate to ask questions.
Thanks.

Comment: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/reference_initialization

Comment: How does nInfo relate to the book's info - nInfo appears to be a set value not a pointer.

Answer (score 3):

The copy of the list's `Book` object into a temporary object happens on this line:

```
Book temp = books.FindByKey(_key)->info;
```

If you want to operate on the List's `Book` object directly instead, you'll want to do this:

```
Book & temp = books.FindByKey(_key)->info;
```

Note the `&` which indicates that `temp` is now a reference-to-a-Book rather than its own independent Book object.